# Boolean difference does not work

Tags: modifiers

I'm relatively new to Blender and I'm trying to apply the Boolean modifier to substract channels from a micro-chip. The problem is the boolean difference does not work for me. 
So I read some advices from similar cases on Stackexchange (remove double vertices, recalculate normal vectors), but the boolean still does not work for me.

Here is the file, feel free to test it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByANiJ_L-B8bSEtkMEtFQjNDTFU

Thank you very much for your help!

Axel

Comment: ur mesh having many reverse faces. select the face and flip them ctrl+N

Answer (score 1):

As I said above, your faces are flipped. You can install the Flippist Addon.
The rest of the steps are shown in the image below:[image]